# how can i get rows from cx_oracle without for loop

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

As said in cx_oracle documentation, for getting rows of a query i should write a for loop. e.g.:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for row in cursor.execute("select * from MyTable"):
        print(row)
```

how can I take these rows without for loop? btw, I may use JSON_OBJECT to directly get JSON from oracle. thanks for your attention:)

Comment: According to [PEP-249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#cursor-methods) the convenient way is to use `fetch[one|many|all]` method of the cursor object rather than looping over `cursor.execute` as long as the result of this call is not defined (i.e. implementation-dependent)

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the rows as a JSON object? Something else? Please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use `while` loop, after fetching all dataset and returning them as may times as the length of the array such as

```py
row = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MyTable').fetchall()

i=0
while i < len(row):
    print(row[i])
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The [cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#fetch-methods) has some alternatives:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from MyTable")
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        break
    print(row)
```

or

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from MyTable")
num_rows = 10
while True:
    rows = cur.fetchmany(num_rows)
    if not rows:
        break
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

or

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from MyTable")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```